# Electron app got cannot find module when run as packaged Mac app

Tags: node.js, macos, browserify, electron

I need some modules from the client process of Electron such as [nodegit](http://www.nodegit.org) or [fs-extra](http://www.nodegit.org). So I installed it using `npm install --save nodegit fs-extra`.

I'm using Browserify with Electron and everything works fine when running the electron app from command line. But when the app is packaged to OSX app, it always fails with error `Cannot find module <module_name>` in `var something = require('some_module')`.

However, if I go to the `app` directory inside the packaged app, `<app_name>.app/Contents/Resources/app`, then run `electron .` from command line, everything works fine.

You can find the sample project [in github](https://github.com/nicnocquee/test-electron).

Versions: Node 5.1.1, Electron 0.36.12. I tried Node 6 and Electron 1, but also failed.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you running browserify in local dev too? Remember browserify is going to parse and replace all `require`s and resolve those modules differently than node would. Honestly, I don't think you even need Browserify here--your client side code is running in a node.js context, so how is browserify providing benefit?